# Polymer hover css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, shadow-dom

I have this simple polymer custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="list-row" attributes="header" >
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style>
            .wrapper
            {
                background-color: #DFF0D8;
                border: 1px solid #468847;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                line-height: 50px;
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
            .wrapper :hover
            {
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: #DFF0B8;
            }
            .wrapper :active
            {
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: #DFF0B8;
            }
            .header
            {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 600;
                color: #468847;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="text-center wrapper">
            <span class="header">{{header}}</span>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('list-row', 
        {
            header: "no header"
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The problem is that the hover (and action - for testing) is not working), why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error on the classes. Remove space.

```
.wrapper:hover
 {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #DFF0B8;
 }
 .wrapper:active
 {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #DFF0B8;
 }
```